cmake use "-std=gnu++1y" in build.ninja while it's only "set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)" in CMakeList.txt
I was trying to build TransformerEngine with pip install .
it gives fatal error: filesystem: No such file or directory
while I'm using GCC 11.2.1.
After checking, in the CMakeLists.txt of TransformerEngine it uses set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17) and in build/cmake/build.ninja the build command for some files using -std=gnu++1y then it cause the error of cannot find filesystem because it's only fully support in c++17 and needs extra flag in c++14.
I want to know why cmake choose -std=gnu++1y when it's set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17) in CMakeLists.txt and how can I force it to c++17.
I'm using ninja 1.10.2 installed from conda.
cmake version is 3.28.0.

Do you set CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD variable before creating a target (with add_library/add_executable)? Please, add to the question post your exact code in form of [mcve].

The code is the TransformerEngine.
Pull the code, then run pip install .
It shows the error of fatal error: filesystem: No such file or directory
From the file transformer_engine/CMakeLists.txt, the CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD is before creating the targets

I solved it with using the cmake installed by conda(3.29.3) rather than cmake in PATH(3.28.0).

"the build command for some files using -std=gnu++1y" - By your words, the problem is related only to some source files. So more details are needed in any case, whether you want to debug the problem by yourself or to ask for help about specifically TransformerEngine project.  My guess is that the problem is somehow related to CUDA code (not C++ one). But I don't want to replicate your environment and run pip install for a given project just for find
